# _doPostBack added twice. one by manual and one by gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a page where i am rendering `GridView.` In GridView i have a `CheckBox` and once you `check`, `uncheck`, Jquery Dialog appears and i need a postback event on that dialog. so i am adding a manual postback on that page. everything is fine till gridview has only 1 page. as soon as gridview has more records, it add a _doPostBack method on page. so i now have a 2 _doPostBack method on page and nothing works because of this.

How can i define in my page that i do not want to add any _doPostBack method by any controls because i have already defined it manually?

## Here is my HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
    <title>Store Management</title>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui.min-1.10.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/assets/styles/StorePortal/style-22012013.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
    <link href="/assets/styles/StorePortal/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
    <link href="../App_Themes/AbleCommerce/ComponentArt.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
    <link href="../App_Themes/AbleCommerce/print.css" rel="stylesheet" type=
    "text/css" />
    <link href="../App_Themes/AbleCommerce/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type=
    "text/css" />
    <link href="../App_Themes/AbleCommerce/webparts.css" rel="stylesheet" type=
    "text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <form action=
    "portal.aspx?q=bbaae796d951c95311f5ec3e599784079c6093ee&amp;q1=COV" id=
    "form1" method="post" name="form1">
        <div>
            <input id="__EVENTTARGET" name="__EVENTTARGET" type="hidden" value=
            "" /> <input id="__EVENTARGUMENT" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" type=
            "hidden" value="" />
        </div><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
        if (!theForm) {
        theForm = document.form1;
        }
        function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
        if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
        }
        }
        //]]>
        </script>

        <div>
            <input id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" type=
            "hidden" value="" />
        </div>
      <script type="text/javascript"> --> this one is added by me manually
//<![CDATA[
        var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
        if (!theForm) {
            theForm = document.form1;
        }
        function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
            if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
                theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
                theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
                theForm.submit();
            }
        }
        //]]>
        </script>

        <div>
            <input id="__EVENTTARGET" name="__EVENTTARGET" type="hidden" value=
            "" /> <input id="__EVENTARGUMENT" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" type=
            "hidden" value="" /> /// sOME CODE HERE
        </div>
     --> this one is added by me manually
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, if i remove the _doPostBack added by me, gridview paging works. BUT when i have only 1 page in gridview, my event in jquery dialog does not work because it cant find _doPostBack.

## ANSWER:

I have removed the _doPostBack() added by me and instead added this on my Page_Load() which adds a _doPostBack() even if there are no asp.net controls which requires this method.

```
ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
```

BIG THANKS TO  @Tim Schmelter for pointing to that LINK

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/archive/2010/06/27/insure-that-dopostback-function-implemented-on-the-page.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, when trying to popup a dialog confirming a record deletion. This is the code I've used (jQuery UI dialog) and it works perfectly.
Don't add a new `doPostBack`. Instead, try to follow this idea. You can adapt it to fit your requirements:

```
// When the user tries to delete a record, show a confirmation.
$(".confirmationButton").click(function(e) {
    // Stop the PostBack
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".confirmationDialog").dialog("open");
}); 

$(".confirmationDialog").dialog({
    buttons: {
    "No": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "Yes": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
            // User confirmed deletion, so carry on with the PostBack.
            eval($("#ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_hdnBtnPostBack").val());
        }
    }
});
```

Somewhere on your code (when checking the page source), you'll find something like this:

```
<input id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_hdnBtnPostBack" type="hidden" value="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$btnDelete','')" name="ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$hdnBtnPostBack">
```

That's the object you will be using with `eval()`.